# MYSQL join condition match only one row based on priority

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I have some posts written in English and Persian (fa) so, my purpose is to get all fa translated posts of each English post and if not exists then get the English default post.

wp_posts table
`897,899,902,1034 are English Posts`
`1019,1035 are Persian Posts`
`1019 is translated post of 902 and 1035 is translated post of 1034`

[image]

These realtions are defined in anothe table called wp_icl_translations
[image]

element_id refers to wp_posts.ID and the post and translated version all have the same trid,`source_language_code of null` means original English post and if it is set to 'en' it means it's a translated post of en language.

---

So the result that I want is :

[image]

I already can get it to this point :

[image]

I need some condition to select only fa if exists and default (en) if it doesn't exist.

Here's the link of full fiddle with all sample data and everything :

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c86dce6ea0b87f863782fbff47e0e526

**It's really important for me to select all the column because this is just a test table the real one has a lot more column which I need to get all of them.**

Here's the complete tables with one row as example :

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=37f8af9fd14c60f4ea23fd4778b86806

Comment: I don't understand your table structure.  It seems to me that there should be a third table which has a language code, post ID, and translation.  Where is this data being stored?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Would you mind checking the fiddle link I think it will be more obvious.There is no other table.wp_posts have original post and also the translated posts all are in wp_posts. wp_icl_translations however can show which one is original and which one is translated and the relations rely on trid column so all the translations and the original post have the same trid value.

Comment: Please do not [delete & repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65836409/3404097), edit. This has all the problems of my comments at your 1st posting. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS But that is consequence of giving a [mre]. PS Please clrify via edits, not comments. PS Put everything need to ask in your post, not just at a link.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] [help] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: Thanks for all the explaination I'll use it next time I'll ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(p2.id, p1.id) id, COALESCE(p2.post_title, p1.post_title) post_title
FROM wp_icl_translations t1
JOIN wp_posts p1 ON t1.element_id = p1.id
LEFT JOIN wp_icl_translations t2 ON t1.trid = t2.trid AND t2.language_code = 'fa'
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p2 ON t2.element_id = p2.id
WHERE t1.language_code = 'en'
ORDER BY id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1e61bb98ec2f2a957e1680e667149908)

---

> I want to use * somehow to get all columns that's really important .. both tables complete create in the fiddle here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=37f8af9fd14c60f4ea23fd4778b86806 – steve moretz

If you need complete columns then you must add one more tables copies and extract the whole rows from them. Primary key needed for such join:

```sql
SELECT p0.*, t0.*
FROM wp_icl_translations t1
JOIN wp_posts p1 ON t1.element_id = p1.id
LEFT JOIN wp_icl_translations t2 ON t1.trid = t2.trid AND t2.language_code = 'fa'
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p2 ON t2.element_id = p2.id
JOIN wp_icl_translations t0 ON t0.translation_id = COALESCE(t2.translation_id, t1.translation_id)
JOIN wp_posts p0 ON p0.id = COALESCE(p2.id, p1.id)
WHERE t1.language_code = 'en'
ORDER BY id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=536ff93ddb1b61c5cdcb964bbfeb1cc6)

Comment: Thank you for this answer amazing only one problem I made wp_posts table simplified in this fiddle and example it has a lot more columns so I want to use * somehow to get all columns that's really important

Comment: I also added my solution using group by which sea eff suggested does the same thing but again I can't select all columns with *.Please check the end of the question I edited and added these informations

Comment: @stevemoretz *I want to use * somehow to get all columns that's really important* Add complete `CREATE TABLE` for both tables into your question (as formatted text). Specify complete list of columns which you need to retrieve.

Comment: the problem is that they can be different depending on different factors I have different tables with different columns which I want to use the same query on all of them and get the same results.For example there are category translations and all kinds of translations different tables but same element_id dependability but columns are different.

Comment: If I could just select the whole row with all its columns it would be perfect.Isn't that possible?

Comment: @stevemoretz Of course this is possible. For this: *Add complete `CREATE TABLE` for both tables into your question (as formatted text).* At least...

Comment: Sure I'll add it in a few minutes thanks.

Comment: @stevemoretz I need in primary key definitions primarily.

Comment: Oh so you need the structure completely I'll send complete structure

Comment: I edited the question and added both tables complete create in the fiddle here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=37f8af9fd14c60f4ea23fd4778b86806

Comment: It works beautifully you keep amazing me sql master.